# How to give a callback function a value a variable has at a specific moment

Tags: javascript

I have the problem, that there is a callback function to which i want to pass another variable. But When the callback function is executed the variable has changed. How can I solve this problem?

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
    var item = data.items[i];


    p.api.get('items.info', {
        itemId: item.id
    }, function (response, item.id) {
        alert(item.id);
        alert(response["tags"][0]["tag"]);
    });
}
```

That is the function im talking about. If somebody could help me i'd be really happy.

Comment: Aaah callbacks in loops =) Look into [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to make unique closures that contain context.

Comment: Don't use `alert()` like a debugging function. Use `console.log()`

Comment: @RUJordan Sometimes `alert` is useful because it pauses JS, though.

Comment: @Oriol true, but depending on the developer tools being used you can use `breakpoints` to pause execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your anonymous function uses context that changes in the loop. It's a common 'problem', with several 'fixes':

1 [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
p.api.get('items.info', {
    itemId: item.id
}, (function (response) {
    // item now comes from `this.item`, not `item`
}).bind({item: item}));
```

2 [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (or whatever they're called these days):

```
p.api.get('items.info', {
    itemId: item.id
}, (function(item) {
    return function (response) {
        // item is now in `item` because a new context was created
    };
})(item));
```

Both are slightly unreadable and unintuitive. There must be better ways, but they depend on your app structure. (Like maybe you can pass context into .get()`?)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put i inside a closure:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
   (function(i) {
    var item = data.items[i];
    p.api.get('items.info', {
        itemId: item.id
    }, function (response, item.id) {
        alert(item.id);
        alert(response["tags"][0]["tag"]);
    });
   })(i);
}
```